# How to use d3 with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I am trying to set up [my d3 charts](https://vinicius-cleves.github.io/enem/visualization/) to use bootstrap dynamic layout. I followed this [tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/d3-js/example/15062/using-bootstrap), but my charts don't load as the page loads. I need to resize the page or click on a button for them to appear.

When working on a development server, everything works fine. But when I serve the static files the onresize event is not called.

How should I render my charts, then? If I render as soon as JS load, width values for divs are 0.

Index.js:

```
window.onresize = ()=>{
  render_charts(); //get width of chart divs using document.getElementById('chart_div_id').clientWidth
  console.log('been here')
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `render_charts()` on `index.js` as it loads does not work on `webpack-dev-server` but works when served as a static file (i don't know why yet). So the following works fine

```
render_charts(); 
window.onresize = ()=>{
  render_charts(); 
};
```